# How to rotate a SAS dataset by 90 degrees?

Tags: matrix, sas

The dataset is 6 rows, 6 columns, like a matrix. I want to rotate it by 90 degrees.
What I have:

```
data have;
  input v1-v6;
  cards;
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
;
run;
```

What I want is a dataset(or just result in log window) like that:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I can achieve this by using array and do loops like this:

```
data _null_;
  array v[6];
  array t[6,6];
  do until(eof);
    set have end=eof;
    i+1;
    do j=1 to 6;
      t[j,i]=v[j];
    end;
  end;

  do i=1 to 6;
    do j=1 to 6;
      put t[i,7-j]@;
    end;
    put;
  end;
run;
```

I am looking for another way to achieve this, maybe `proc iml`?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Are you just reversing the order of the values in a row?  Or are you actually transposing the matrix?

Comment: @Tom rotating the matrix by 90 degrees, just like rotating a box from vertical to landscape. But your renaming-method slove this dataset more effective.

Comment: Rotating a box by 90 degrees is what a TRANSFORM does.  The first column becomes the first row.  What you seem to be doing is reflecting the matrix around a vertical axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the Rot270() function from [Rotating matrices using SAS/IML](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/10/18/rotating-matrices.html).

```
proc iml;
start Rot270(m);
   return(T(m[nrow(m):1,])); /* up-down flip, then transpose */
finish;
 
m = {1 1 1 0 0 0,
     1 1 0 0 0 0,
     1 0 1 0 0 0,
     0 0 0 1 0 0,
     0 0 0 0 1 0,
     0 0 0 0 0 1};
m270 = rot270(m);
print m270;
```

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

More generally, rotating a matrix is accomplished by the following one-line SAS/IML functions:

```
proc iml;
start Rot90(m);
   return(T(m[,ncol(m):1]));       /* left-right flip, then transpose */
finish;
 
start Rot180(m);
   return(m[nrow(m):1,ncol(m):1]); /* left-right flip, up-down flip */
finish;
 
start Rot270(m);
   return(T(m[nrow(m):1,]));       /* up-down flip, then transpose */
finish;
 
m = {1 1 1 0 0 0,
     1 1 0 0 0 0,
     1 0 1 0 0 0,
     0 0 0 1 0 0,
     0 0 0 0 1 0,
     0 0 0 0 0 1};
m90 = rot90(m);
m180 = rot180(m);
m270 = rot270(m);
print m m90 m180 m270;
```

```
    m                m90  
1 1 1 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0      0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0      1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0      1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1      1 1 1 0 0 0

    m180             m270  
1 0 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0      0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1      0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1      0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1      1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Very impressive! Are you Rick Wicklin? I have searched "SAS dataset rotate" but just missed this article.

Comment: @whymath I wish I was! I remembered reading this article a couple of months ago :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to reverse the order within the rows then just rename the variables.

```
 data want(rename=(z1-z6=v1-v6));
   retain z1-z6;
   set have(rename=(v1-v6=z6-z1));
 run;
```

If you really want to rotate it 90 degrees just use PROC TRANPOSE.

```
 proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=v;
    var v1-v6 ;
 run;
```

But the result is something different than you show.

```
Obs    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6

 1      1     1     1     0     0     0
 2      1     1     0     0     0     0
 3      1     0     1     0     0     0
 4      0     0     0     1     0     0
 5      0     0     0     0     1     0
 6      0     0     0     0     0     1
```

You could get what you want by reversing the order of the rows and columns that go into PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
 data for_transpose;
   row+1;
   set have;
 run;
 proc sort ; by descending row; run;
 proc transpose data=for_transpose out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=v;
   var v6-v1 ;
 run;
```

Comment: Really tricky way, I haven't think like that before. I stubborned to do the rotating thing>_<

Comment: If you want to reverse the order of the values in a row there is no need think of the dataset as a matrix.  The values needed for a given observation are all there on that observation.

Comment: `proc transpose` works! I will think it further. Thank you.